# Why does .shape with PNG size have dimension of 4 instead of 3?

Tags: python, png

I am trying to use a .png file in a CNN with TensorFlow and have this trouble where I get a strange shape when I import a .png file.

```
Png_file = mpimg.imread("201537.png")
Png_file.shape
```

and get the output as (255, 255, 4).
I get that the file is 255 pixels x 255 pixels but isnt the last number meaning RGB so it should be 3 and not 4?

Answer (score 0):

PNG images support transparency. The transparency value per pixel is contained as another channel besides the 3 color channels for red, green, and blue.

The transparency channel is also called "alpha channel" and the image mode is therefore called RGBA.

Comment: Super thanks to you. This enabled me to solve the issue. TensorFlow it self converts .PNG to RGB, but when I tried to use an PNG to do a prediction it did not transform the image to RGB.